# Как удержать TCP соединение открытым при переподключении к интернету?

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, 3g

Имеется:

- Ноутбук с Linux Ubuntu 16.04.2,
- 3G модем с USB интерфейсом,
- SSH доступ к арендованному VPS.

Проблема: интернет-модем глючит и отключается, поработав пару минут. Если его
переподключить, связь снова восстанавливается, но лишь на две минуты. Причём
при разрыве связи TCP соединения, инициированные с ноутбука, зависают, но не
разрываются. Например, утилита **nc** в этот момент не выдаёт никаких ошибок.

Вопрос: возможно ли как-то организовать туннель до моего VPS так, чтобы он не
зависал и не разрывался, а передача данных продолжалась бы при повторном
подключении к Интернет?

Что удалось достичь: с помощью инструмента Mobile Shell из пакета [mosh](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mosh)
можно устроить непрерываемую SSH-сессию на сервере. Но увы, mosh не понимает
параметр `-D` при вызове из командной строки. (Этот параметр клиента OpenSSH
позволяет организовать SOCKS прокси с выходом в Интернет через удалённый
сервер).

Таким образом удаётся устроить бесшовную сессию командной оболочки при
переподключениях к сети. Но как быть с почтовой программой или
веб-обозревателем?